# how to insert a document with current date and type date on mongodb compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

am using mongodb compass app on windows, i want to insert a document manually from the ui with current date.

i need the app to capture the current time and insert it with the doucment as date type,

```
"momentAdded":{
  "$date":true
}
```

the above code is returning
**1970-01-01T00:00:00.001+00:00**

Answer (score 6):

In the Compass's Documents tab, ADD DATA -> Insert Document. You will find a dialog as shown in the picture.

[image]

Select the VIEW "Field-by-Field Editor" mode (the other one is the JSON mode). To create a new date field - enter example field name `"dob"`, then select field type as `Date`, and enter date value (for example `2021-07-15T11:30:45`). This will be saved as a date field in your collection's document. See [Compass - Insert Document](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/documents/insert/#insert-documents).

If you use the "JSON" VIEW, then create the date field with this syntax:

```
{
  "dob": { "$date": "2021-07-15T10:30:48.021Z" }
}
```

The newly inserted document will look like in the below picture. And, you can verify the field type is `Date` in the [Analyze Your Data Schema](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/schema/#analyze-your-data-schema) tab.

[image]

Comment: is there is a way to make it auto fetch the current date and time ? instead of adding it manual

like
dob: new Date()

Comment: I don't know/think there is such default assignment in Compass. You can do a manual update from command-line `mongo` shell for multiple documents.